# How to pass data between SplashScreen and ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

When application starts, function check if is internet connection. If "yes" Splash Screen pass the info about it to View Controller. But here I have a problem because between SplashScreen and ViewController is Navigation Controller. It looks like this:

[Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjdGg.jpg)

I pass the data from Splash Screen using this function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let VC:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
    VC.connection = isConnection

// connection is a bool var in VievController
}
```

but when I decided to use NavigationController Xcode receive me information about error like this "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1835cec) to 'DKTV_Reader.ViewController' (0x23888)" showing my in this time line:

```
let VC:ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
```

before I used NAvigationController this solution has worked perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired `ViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, so technically it is not the `destinationViewController`, but rather the `UINavigationController` is. The `destinationViewController` that you want is the navigation controller's first view controller which you can then optionally cast as the type `ViewController`

```
let destination = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? ViewController
destination?.connection = isConnection
```